# Replace empty values with values of other records in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have the following problem

I need to replace the empty cel values in dataframe with the values of the costs of CustomerNr of other records

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1004,''], [1004, 'D'],[1005, 'C'], 
                   [1010,'A'], [1010,''],[1010,''],[1010,''],[1004, '']], columns=['CustomerNr','Costs'])
```

| CustomerNr | Costs |
| --- | --- |
| 1004 |  |
| 1004 | D |
| 1005 | C |
| 1010 | A |
| 1010 |  |
| 1010 |  |
| 1010 |  |
| 1004 |  |

Desired output:

| CustomerNr | Costs |
| --- | --- |
| 1004 | D |
| 1004 | D |
| 1005 | C |
| 1010 | A |
| 1010 | A |
| 1010 | A |
| 1010 | A |
| 1004 | D |

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [bfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html)

```py
>>> df1.replace("", pd.NA).ffill().bfill()
   CustomerNr Costs
0        1004     D
1        1004     D
2        1005     C
3        1010     A
4        1010     A
5        1010     A
6        1010     A
7        1004     A
```

Answer (score 0):

You cn do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1004,''], [1004, 'D'],[1005, 'C'], 
                   [1010,'A'], [1010,''],[1010,''],[1010,''],[1004, '']], columns=['CustomerNr','Costs'])

df1['Costs'] = df1['Costs'].replace('', np.nan)  # Replace empty cells with NaNs
print(df1)
df1['Costs'] = df1.groupby('CustomerNr')['Costs'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')

print(df1)
```

which gives

```
   CustomerNr Costs
0        1004     D
1        1004     D
2        1005     C
3        1010     A
4        1010     A
5        1010     A
6        1010     A
7        1004     D
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the module:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Create the input DataFrame:

```
f1 = pd.DataFrame([[1004,''], [1004, 'D'],[1005, 'C'], [1010,'A'], [1010,''],[1010,''],[1010,''],[1004, '']], columns=['CustomerNr','Costs'])
```

Create a dictionary of values that map `CustomerNr` to its respective `Costs`:

```
costs_dict = f1[f1['Costs'] != ''].set_index('CustomerNr')['Costs'].to_dict()
```

Replace the empty cells with the values of `Costs` of the respective `CustomerNr`:

```
f1['Costs'] = f1['Costs'].fillna(f1['CustomerNr'].map(costs_dict))
```